# Is $1/x$ a tempered distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

If $f$ is a integrable function, then, $f$ is a tempered distribution by
$$T_f(\varphi)=\int f\varphi,\quad \varphi \text{ Schwartz function }$$

However, I read that the function $f(x)=1/x,\, x\in\mathbb{R}$, despite not being integrable, is still a tempered distribution. Why? Where I cand found a reference in which this result appears? Thank.

Comment: $1/x$ isn't even a distribution since the integral against a bump function supported near 0 is $\infty$. There are some ways of defining a sort of $1/x$ using limits.

Comment: But I understand  that the function $1/z$ belongs to the space $(S(\mathbb{R}^2)^{*})$ (I suppose that $z=x+iy$ but I don't know) that's why I made this topic, a to understand a simpler case and then try to understand the more complicated one.

Comment: You do sometimes see a distribution denoted $\text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}$.  See the answer by Princess.  or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3578392/442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can define a tempered distribution, in the sense of the [Cauchy principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). Define the distribution $f$, sometimes called $\mathrm{P.\!\!V.} \frac 1 x$, by the rule
$$\begin{align*}
f[\varphi] 
&:= \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&\equiv \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&\equiv \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \int_\varepsilon^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x) - \varphi(-x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&=2 \varphi'(0)
\end{align*}$$
for $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. For $\varphi$ a Schwarz function instead, we end up with instead
$$
|f[\varphi]| \le 2 \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\varphi'(x)| \qquad 
|f[\varphi]| \le 2 \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x \varphi (x)|
$$
(I don't know if we can do better than a bound in the Schwarz case.)

This particular example is discussed in more detail on the Wikipedia page linked above. (I got it from Vretblad's *Fourier Analysis and Its Applications* as I'm working through it recently.)